# Is there a way to show a progressbar on Github Wiki?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, github, github-flavored-markdown

I want to show the progress of the current iteration of my project on Github Wiki. However I couldn't find a way to do this.

I am looking for something similar to the [Bootstrap progress bars](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress) without any interaction. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use this link as an image:

`https://progress-bar.dev/<thepercentage>`

Example: `![50%](https://progress-bar.dev/50)` [image: 50%]

If you want to add a title like shields.io:

`https://progress-bar.dev/<thepercentage>?title=<title>` [image: Example]

More documentation can be found [here](https://progress-bar.dev).

Comment: Similar alternative: https://geps.dev/progress/10

Answer (score 24):

You can use the **power of emojis** to depict the intents of progress bars.

### Simple symbols

**Checkboxes:**

⏹⏹⏹⏹⏹

⬜️⬜️⬜️⬜️

✅✅✅✅✅

⏹⬛️⬛️⬛️⬛️

**Numbers:**

1️⃣2️⃣3️⃣4️⃣❎6️⃣7️⃣8️⃣9️⃣

**Shapes:**

⚪️⚪️⚪️⚪️⚪️⚪️⚪️

❤️❤️❤️❤️❤️❤️

❤️❤️

### Out of the box

**Surfer and waves:**

〰️〰️〰️〰️〰️

**Footballer and goal:**

➖➖➖⚽️➖➖➖➖➖‍♂️

Feel free to use your creativity with emojis to create more such progress bars!

Here's a [good resource](https://github.com/ikatyang/emoji-cheat-sheet/blob/master/README.md#symbols).